# Show & Hide content based on a radio

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a radio button that hides/shows a content area, but how do I check what value is selected on load?

This is the code  that I am using right now

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#CONTENT_DIV").hide();

    $("input:radio[name='SHOW_HIDE_CONTENT']").change(function(){  
        if(this.value == 'y' && this.checked){
          $("#CONTENT_DIV").show();
        }else{
          $("#CONTENT_DIV").hide();
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply trigger the change event after attaching the event:

```
$("input:radio[name='SHOW_HIDE_CONTENT']").change(function(){  
    if(this.value == 'y' && this.checked){
      $("#CONTENT_DIV").show();
    }else{
      $("#CONTENT_DIV").hide();
    }
}).change(); //trigger change to see changes
```

Comment: This does not address the issue of reading the value of the radio button (Value is not always the same, sometimes it will be checked and visible but not always)

Comment: @YacoZaragoza: do you mean like this `("input:radio[name='SHOW_HIDE_CONTENT']:checked").val()`